# Can we capture commands written on git bash client in git hooks

Tags: git, bash, git-bash

I want to capture the commands that user gives on git bash client in the git hooks. Basically, idea is to log all these details to some logging system through the git hooks. I was able to get the commit message using

```
MESSAGE=$(git log -1 HEAD --pretty=format:%s)
```

But what if user provides any other option from the various other options available in git commit. How can I get those in bash script.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. What does it mean to "capture the commands that user gives on git bash client in the git hooks"?

Comment: Lets say I execute `git commit -m "commit message" --author "abc@xyz.com"`. Now when this command is executed, pre-commit hook is called by git. In that hook, I want to get the parameters provided to this commit command (like commit message and author in the above example)  Then I will store these values to some other db / logging system like Seri logs. Let me know if its still not clear.